# database return as an array and no result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if you could be able to help me. I'm trying to print the rows when I click on my website link, example: `mysite.com/myscript.php?channels=abc&id=101`.

When I try this:

```
if($channels && $id) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
       echo $row;
    }
    mysql_close();
    exit;
  }
```

I will get the return string as `array`.

Can you please help me how I can get the results when i'm using `echo` under the while loop to get the results I want?

Comment: as the name suggest `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array - to see the contents run: `print_r($row)` please read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: as your new, stop using `mysql_*` switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: @Dagon thank you very much for this, i'm getting the results which it show `rray ( [0] => 101 [id] => 101 [1] => ABC FAMILY [channels] => ABC FAMILY [2] => http://www.tvguide.com/tvlistings/channelsNum=10093&channel=12/ [links] => http://www.tvguide.com/tvlistings/channelsNum=10093&channel=12)` so how i can check the links in a database to see if i can compare it before I call the tvguidecom function?

Comment: i dont know what " check the links in a database to see if i can compare it before I call the tvguidecom function" means

Comment: well you know what i mean, you can see that i get the results `[links] => http://www.tvguide.com/tvlistings/channelsNum=10093&channel=12)`. I want to check the column name called `links` to see if i can get the return string of `tvguide.com` and I want to compare it before i could do something. How I could do that?

Comment: clearly you are getting the string "http://www.tvguide.com/tvlistings/channelsNum=10093&channel=12"

Comment: yes but i want to compare it to see if the boolean is true, example: `if($row['links'] == 'tvguide')`

Comment: Rob - see answer below

Comment: you're missing `$_GET`'s - this `if($channels && $id)` does nothing, unless you're not showing us full code as to where/how those variables are assigned.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for letting me know. can you please show me how i can add the `$_GET` in this line `if($channels && $id)`?

Comment: if you accepted Dagon's answer, then I don't see why you need to know how to use a GET array; can you elaborate on that and why do you want to use GET arrays? Since, and again... you've accepted Dagon's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably not the whole answer but its hard to work like this in the comments:

```
if (strpos($row['links'],'tvguide') !== false) {
echo 'tvguide found';
}
```

if you only want links with that text returned from the db, you should do it in the db query

Comment: [I've a feeling...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767997/database-return-as-an-array-and-no-result#comment49589110_30767997) *tingly spidey sense?*

Comment: *Hah*...will ya lookah dat? It went *green* all of a sudden; *nice.*

Comment: i shouldn't bother with questions that require psychic powers @Fred-ii-

Comment: yeah well it looks like you've hit the nail right on the barrelhead.

Comment: how did he get the shown results if that was the issue?

Comment: dunno... you'll need to ask the OP.

Comment: no thanks i get to deal with enough idiots at work ;-)

Comment: [Did I suddenly open up a can of *you know what?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767997/database-return-as-an-array-and-no-result#comment49589284_30767997)